# Gallery on website

Tags: php, jquery, image, gallery

I made this: http://tatertotz.org/gallery

And I want the gallery on the bottom to load all the images in a directory but the gallery itself will not load.

Comment: We are very sad for this. What have you tried?

Comment: Hmm, you mean after the spinning circle, no images appear? They do appear here, I've just seen them, cute kids :D

Comment: You should at least provide a bit more information about the used gallery framework or the basics of the page (directory where the images are, page structure, scripts). Nobody can help you if you just point to a page and say "it's not working"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing: Your hyperlink of a picture shows "**gallerydata**/Season 1/100_1578.jpg" and this works (points to an image), the image however tries to display "**data/gallery**/Season 1/100_1578.jpg", which doesn't work because it's not the same.

Try fixing the path and see if it makes any difference. Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked except galleria will still not load

Answer (score 1):

You should use // for commenting - it's breaking your script

```
$('#gallery').galleria({
   width: 700,
   height: 467 --I made heights match // <--
   // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
});
```

Comment: That worked except galleria will still not load